# How to get the parameters from url without notice

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, cookies

So I was thinking of a way to remove the parameters from url when page is downloaded to client and respond different in each different value of the get parameter.

Let me take it clearer for you. Say I have this url: **www.abc.com/?q=jsdfnjns**. Ideally, I am thinking of shortening this url with goo.gl and then send it to the customer. When customer clicks on it, it will automatically go to **www.abc.com** clean url and set a cookie to the client with the q's value. I have seen it before in many affiliate links except that the initial url had no get parameters but value was actually a sub-folder e.g **www.abc.com/jsdfnjns**

So what's the way to actually get the value of a get parameter and manipulate it with php, while removed from the url without user's notice, or setting a cookie when parameter is given as a sub-folder. I suspect it must be some htaccess rules and php tricks but can't find a way.

With given url **www.abc.com/jsdfnjns** how can i redirect immediately to **www.abc.com** 
and have the **jsdfnjns** saved ideally server-side in apache or in a user cookie ?
Is there any way to make it also happen with actual get parameters too ?

And a schematic:

**www.abc.com/jsdfnjns** convert it to -> goo.gl/sjbjsb -> when clicked, user is going to **www.abc.com** but somehow i get the **jsdfnjns** and respond in the main page different.

Hope my question is well defined, any ideas will be appreciated.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly you need to set .htaccess file

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?q=$1 [QSA,L]

</IfModule>
```

index.php code:

```
session_start();

if(isset($_REQUEST['q'])) {
    $_SESSION['q'] = $_REQUEST['q'];
    header('Location:index.php');
    die();
}
else{
    if(isset($_SESSION['q'])) $q = $_SESSION['q'];
    else $q = null;
    //YOUR CODE
    var_dump($q);
}
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for the fast reply.
Your code is working awesome!! Thank you very much :)
The only changes I did were to remove the ifmodule tags and apply strip_tags, trim and htmlspecialchars to $_SESSION['q']. Thanks again buddy!

Comment: Something else, what am I supposed to change for the client to actually see in the bar just the site without index.php ?

Comment: Change header('Location:index.php'); to header('Location:http://yoursitedomain.com'); (with http://)

Comment: Perfect!
Thought I had to change something in .htaccess.
Thanks buddy :)